# What ~ is parsed to?

Tags: bash

When I run following commands:

```
if [ -d "~/Desktop" ]; then echo "exists"; fi
if [ -d "/bin" ]; then echo "exists"; fi
```

The first command echoes nothing, and the second echoes "exists". Why "~" is not understood by bash? Seems

```
if [ -d ~/Desktop ]; then echo "exists"; fi
if [[ -d ~/Desktop ]]; then echo "exists"; fi
```

will work. Is it possible to use quote with ~? The shell is bash. Thanks!

Comment: if [[ -d "$HOME/Desktop" ]]; then echo "exists"; fi -> this is OK.

Comment: tried escaping the `~`?

Comment: The first line of Tilde Expansion in Bash manual saith, "If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (‘~’)..." ([Link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~` is not expanded inside quotes. Try

```
if [ -d "$HOME/Desktop" ]; then echo "exists"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, i.e. `"~/Desktop"`, the tilde doesn't get expanded as it is treated as a literal.

Use `eval` to expand:

```
dir="~/Desktop"
eval dir=$dir
if [ -d "$dir" ]; then echo "exists"; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing ~ with $HOME. **Tilde expansion only happens when the tilde is unquoted**

Instead use :

```
if [ -d "$HOME/Desktop" ]; then echo "exists"; fi
```